# echo is not working in PHP form

Tags: php, html

Echo is not printing fname. Please let me know why echo is not working.  Echo is not printing fname.

html form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PHP Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="submit.php" method="post">
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>New Users</legend>

                <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>

                <label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>

                <label for="Username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"requiredrequiredrequired>
                <br >

                <input type="Submit" required name="submit"value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $fname = $_post["fname"];  echo  $fname; ?>    
        <?php $lname= $_post["lname"]; ?>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `$_POST` ... Variable names are case sensitive

Comment: If you need to repeat yourself because SO tells you your question is not good enough, maybe make your question better instead of repeating yourself. If you need to repeat yourself because SO tells you your question is not good enough, maybe make your question better instead of repeating yourself. If you need to repeat yourself because SO tells you your question is not good enough, maybe make your question better instead of repeating yourself.

Comment: @deceze and repeating and repeating...

Answer (score 3):

change

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $fname = $_post["fname"];  echo  $fname; ?>    
        <?php $lname= $_post["lname"]; ?>     
    </body>
</html>
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $fname = $_POST["fname"];  echo  $fname; ?>    
        <?php $lname= $_POST["lname"]; ?>     
    </body>
</html>
```

I think it's because post variable needs to be in upper case

```
(PHP 4 >= 4.1.0, PHP 5)
$_POST -- $HTTP_POST_VARS [deprecated] — HTTP POST variables
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Still **not working** :(

Comment: write `var_dump($_POST)` in submit.php and see what it gives you

Comment: print var_dump($_POST) only.. I cannot see my first or last name

Comment: make sure that you have correct link to your submit.php in form action field.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your `html` first.
Is it true you write like this?

```
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"requiredrequiredrequired>
```

I try it and it work.
I create echo.php.
Test this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $fname = $_POST["fname"];  echo  $fname;     
      $lname= $_POST["lname"]; echo $lname;
    ?>

    <form action="echo.php" method="post">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <fieldset>
      <legend>New Users</legend>

      <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />

      <label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />

      <label for="Username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
      <br >

      <input type="Submit" required name="submit"value="Submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can make more beautiful code.

Comment: Oh!! Even this code is not printing echo .When I click on submit button I see PHP CODEs

Comment: hah? can you post print screen or something? i don't understand you. If you want to ask please give the good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
NOTE :For easiness, i joined both of the page together and named it as submit.php. U can separate it

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST["fname"])){
    ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <title>Document</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <?php $fname = $_POST["fname"];
                        echo  $fname;
                        $lname= $_POST["lname"];
                        echo $lname?>     
                    </body>
                </html>
    <?php
        }
        else{
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>PHP Form</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="submit.php" method="post">
                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>New Users</legend>

                    <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>

                    <label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>

                    <label for="Username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"requiredrequiredrequired>
                    <br >

                    <input type="Submit" required name="submit"value="Submit">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php }?>
```